# Definition of gs function is when you call the function from html code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm creating gas web application using gs file and html include script tag and jQuery.
When I execute below program ① or ②, then ③ is displayed on browser in each ①, ②.

### ①↓

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("hello");
}

var closerRe = function (){
    var b = 0;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        if (plusOr == 1){
            ++b;
        }
        return b;
    };
}();

function closer(x){
  var tmp = closerRe(x);
  Logger.log("tmp = " + tmp);
  return tmp;
}
```

### ②↓

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("hello").evaluate();
}

var closer = function closer(){
    var b = 0;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        if (plusOr == 1){
            ++b;
        }
        return b;
    };
}();
```

### below is common html file used with ① and ②

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="wi"></p>
    <script>
    var count = 0;

    function success(get){
      ++count;
      document.getElementById("wi").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<p>get = " + get + ", count = " + count + "</p>");
      if (count < 4){
        aa(1);
      }      
    }

    aa(1);

    function aa(vv){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).closer(vv);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### ③ : here is displayed on browser

```
get = 1, count = 4

get = 1, count = 3

get = 1, count = 2

get = 1, count = 1
```

**question : Definition of gs function is when you call the function from html code? (Can I use closer in gs file from html?)**

Thank you.

---

Postscript①

I want the "get =" and "count =" values to be the same displayed on browser. with using closer function of JavaScript in gs file(In other word, using "closer" name function I wrote in ① and ②)

Comment: Do you want the `get` and `count` values to be the same? `get =  4, count = 4`, `get = 3, count = 3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the following result.

  ```
  get = 4, count = 4

  get = 3, count = 3

  get = 2, count = 2

  get = 1, count = 1
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- About `closer()`,

  - The value cannot be received because of no arguments.
  - Only when `plusOr` is `1`, `++b` is run.
- About `success()`

  - The initial value of `vv` is `1`. So when above modification is reflected, at the 1st loop, `get` of `success(get)` is `2`.
  - At the if statement of `if (count < 4){aa(1);}`, `1` is always sent.

When above modification is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

For Google Apps Script, please modify as follows.

#### For pattern 1:

From:

```
var closerRe = function (){
    var b = 0;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        if (plusOr == 1){
            ++b;
        }
        return b;
    };
}();
```

To:

```
var closerRe = function (x){
    var b = x;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        ++b;
        return b;
    }(x);
};
```

#### For pattern 2:

From:

```
var closer = function closer(){
    var b = 0;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        if (plusOr == 1){
            ++b;
        }
        return b;
    };
}();
```

To:

```
var closer = function closer(x){
    var b = x;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        ++b;
        return b;
    }(x);
};
```

and for HTML, please modify the script in the function of `success()` as follows.

#### From:

```
document.getElementById("wi").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<p>get = " + get + ", count = " + count + "</p>");
if (count < 4){
  aa(1);
}
```

#### To:

```
document.getElementById("wi").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<p>get = " + (get - 1) + ", count = " + count + "</p>"); // modified
if (count < 4){
  aa(get); // modified
}
```

### Note:

- I think that in your case, as a simple script, you can also use `function closer(x){return ++x}` instead of above modified `closer()`.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

The following additional script uses Properties service.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("hello");
}

function clearProperty() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("b");
}

var closerRe = function (){
    var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var value = prop.getProperty("b");
    var b = value ? Number(value) : 0;
    return function(plusOr){
        Logger.log("plusor = " + plusOr);
        if (plusOr == 1){
            ++b;
            prop.setProperty("b", b);
        }
        return b;
    };
}();

function closer(x){
  var tmp = closerRe(x);
  Logger.log("tmp = " + tmp);
  return tmp;
}
```

#### HTML side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="wi"></p>
    <script>
    var count = 0;

    function success(get){
      ++count;
      document.getElementById("wi").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<p>get = " + get + ", count = " + count + "</p>");
      if (count < 4){
        aa(1);
      } else {
        google.script.run.clearProperty();
      }
    }

    aa(1);

    function aa(vv){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).closer(vv);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)
- [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache)

  - In your case, I think that Cache service can be also used.

Comment: @容易いtayasui If this answer was not the result you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer. The reason why we should give argument to outer function(closerRe) in "For pattern 1:" is because of we only could call function unit in gs file If we want to execute program of gs file?

Comment: @容易いtayasui Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: Sorry, I am confusing. So, about the ① code in my question section. The closerRe is Immediately Invoked Function Expression, So, I think closerRe variable should have inner function. thus, about the code "closerRe(x)" in ①, I think this argument "x" will be assignmented to plusOr variable. And, the reason why I couldn't get result of "get =" equal 1-4 is because of When I called the closerRe function through closer function, the "var b = 0;" code was excuted for each time?

Comment: @容易いtayasui In the case of `var closerRe = function (){###}();`, when `closerRe` by `closerRe(x)` is run, `plusOr` is the value of `x`. But `b = 0` is used. So when `x` is except for `1`, `0` is returned. And in your HTML side, `1` is always returned from `closerRe` by `aa(1)`. So I modified the script to count up. I think that there are several modifications for your case. I think that when my modified HTML is used, `closerRe` can be also modified to `var closerRe = function (){return function(plusOr){return ++plusOr}}();`. If this was not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Thanks to your answer, I could understand that every time the function in gs file is defined when I call function in gs file from cliend side using google.script.run. because each time  b = 0 used, when i call closerRe function. So, the question was resolved.

Comment: @容易いtayasui Thank you for replying. As one way for using a value between Google Apps Script side and HTML side, I think that PropertiesService and CacheService can be also used. When the PropertiesService is used, the value can be saved to the GAS project and you can get the value from the PropertiesService. I added the sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If this sample could help you understand about the scripts of Google Apps Script side and HTML side, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks a lots for give me useful information. They will help me for making good apps!